# Send ajax request to a file inside Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-post

I am trying to send an ajax request to a page that is loaded inside the Jquery Dialog box.
This is my dialog box code:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: false,
        open: function ()
        {
            $(this).load('window.php');
        },         
        height: 240,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Ajax Page'
    });
```

Now i have a link in my page, that sends ajax request to the "window.php" page, on click:

```
 $.post("window.php", { username: username }
```

And in the loaded page (window.php), i put the code to print the post parameters...

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
var_dump($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
echo ':: '.$_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

But to my surprise, i am not getting any request parameters printed in the loaded page of dialog box. I am just getting `Hello world`. What could be the issue?

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you trying to send data from your parent page of the modal to the actual modal window?
I guess so.
I am not sure you can do that really, because the post data you send aren't sent to the page loaded in the modal window AFAIK.

Comment: Yes.. i am trying to send data from my parent page to the jquery modal box.

Comment: Your problem is that the response is not loaded in your dialog box? or is it that the request is not being made to window.php?

Comment: I see that the request is not being made to window.php.
The post request is not getting catched in the window.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      $('#dialog').html(data);
    });
```

Comment: OP is using PHP and not html. OP is also creating a dialog. Might want to edit your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I have correctly understood your problem. But I feel that you want something to be posted to window.php and its response should be displayed in the dialog box.

you can do it this way:

favorite

I am trying to send an ajax request to a page that is loaded inside the Jquery Dialog box. This is my dialog box code:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: false,
    open: function ()
    {
        $.ajax(function(){
            url:"window.php",
            data:{ 'username' : username},   // now depends from where you are bringing this username from
            type:"post",
            sucess:function(msg){
                $('#dialog').html(msg)
            }
        });
   },         
   height: 240,
   width: 400,
   title: 'Ajax Page'
});
```

I do not understand the motive behing user `$.load()`. Load is an event that triggers when something is completely loaded in the browser. But you are calling it on open event of Dialog. Did you intended using `.load()` as a synonym for `.html()` ?

Answer (score 0):

add a var_dump($_POST) to see what's wrong. Maybe:

```
$.post("window.php", { 'username' : username }
```

Comment: I have done as you said. Added: echo 'Hello world';
var_dump($_POST); at the top of my "window.php" page, and i got the output as: Hello worldarray(0) {} by default. But nothing is getting updated in the dialog box, after sending an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i tried this one, after following Sandeep's post, and this seems to be working:

```
$.post('window.php', {"username":"john"}, function(data) {

        $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: false,                     
        height: 240,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Ajax Page'
        }).html(data);
        });
```